# Assigning (or tieing in) function results back to original data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, return, function

I am struggling with extracting the regression coefficients once I complete the function call np.polyfit (actual code below). I am able to get a display of each coefficient but am unsure how to actually extract them for future use with the original data.

```
df=pd.read_csv('2_skews.csv')
```

Here is a head() of the data

```
      date      expiry   symbol   strike vol
0  6/10/2015  1/19/2016    IBM      50  42.0
1  6/10/2015  1/19/2016    IBM      55  41.5
2  6/10/2015  1/19/2016    IBM      60  40.0
3  6/10/2015  1/19/2016    IBM      65  38.0
4  6/10/2015  1/19/2016    IBM      70  36.0
```

There are many symbols with many strikes across many days and many expiry dates as well

I have grouped the data by date, symbol and expiry and then call the regression function with this:

```
df_reg=df.groupby(['date','symbol','expiry']).apply(regress)
```

I have this function that seems to work well (gives proper coefficients), i just don't seem to be able to access them and tie them to the original data.

```
def regress(df):
    y=df['vol']
    x=df['strike']
    z=P.polyfit(x,y,4)
return (z)
```

I am calling polyfit like this:

```
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P
```

The final results:

```
df_reg


date       symbol  expiry   
5/19/2015  GS      1/19/2016    [-112.064833151, 6.76871521993, -0.11147562136...
                   3/21/2016    [-131.2914493, 7.16441276062, -0.1145534833, 0...
           IBM     1/19/2016    [211.458028147, -5.01236287512, 0.044819313514...
                   3/21/2016    [-34.1027973807, 3.16990194634, -0.05676206572...
6/10/2015  GS      1/19/2016    [50.3916788503, 0.795484227762, -0.02701849495...
                   3/21/2016    [31.6090441114, 0.851878910113, -0.01972772270...
           IBM     1/19/2016    [-13.6159660078, 3.23002791603, -0.06015739505...
                   3/21/2016    [-51.6709051223, 4.80288173687, -0.08600312989...
dtype: object
```

the top results has the functional form of :

```
y = -0.000002x4 + 0.000735x3 - 0.111476x2 + 6.768715x - 112.064833
```

I have tried to take the constructive criticism of previous individuals and make my question as clear as possible, please let me know if i still need to work on this :-)

John

Comment: Try changing the output of ```regress``` to ```pd.Series(z)```. The output of the groupby will be a data frame with a column for each polynomial. This should give you easy access and allow you to carry out further calculations such as computing the predictied values from the observations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the output of `regress` to a Series rather than a numpy array will give you a data frame when you groupby. The index of the series will be the column names:

```
In [37]:

df = pd.DataFrame(
[[  '6/10/2015',  '1/19/2016',    'IBM',      50,  42.0],
[ '6/10/2015',  '1/19/2016',    'IBM',      55,  41.5],
[  '6/10/2015',  '1/19/2016',    'IBM',      60,  40.0],
[  '6/10/2015',  '1/19/2016',    'IBM',      65,  38.0],
[  '6/10/2015',  '1/19/2016',    'IBM',      70,  36.0]],
columns=['date', 'expiry', 'symbol', 'strike', 'vol'])

def regress(df):
    y=df['vol']
    x=df['strike']
    z=np.polyfit(x,y,4)
    return pd.Series(z, name='order', index=range(5)[::-1])

group_cols = ['date', 'expiry', 'symbol']
coeffs = df.groupby(group_cols).apply(regress)
coeffs


Out[40]:
                         order         4      3          2         1    0
date           expiry   symbol                  
6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM -5.388312e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333   -118
```

To get the columns containing the coefficients for each combination of date, expiry and symbol you can then merge `df` and `coeffs` on these columns:

```
In [25]: df.merge(coeffs.reset_index(), on=group_cols)
Out[25]:
date    expiry     symbol   strike    vol    4              3               2          1       0
0   6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM 50  42.0    -6.644454e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333    -118
1   6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM 55  41.5    -6.644454e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333    -118
2   6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM 60  40.0    -6.644454e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333    -118
3   6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM 65  38.0    -6.644454e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333    -118
4   6/10/2015   1/19/2016   IBM 70  36.0    -6.644454e-18   0.000667    -0.13   8.033333    -118
```

You can then do something like

```
df = df.merge(coeffs.reset_index(), on=group_cols)
strike_powers = pd.DataFrame(dict((i, df.strike**i) for i in range(5))
df['modelled_vol'] = (strike_powers * df[range(5)]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Could I trouble you to provide an example of how I can use the coefficients, my skill-set is rather low (new to python) and the phrase 'easily' is not in my python vocabulary yet. Perhaps by using them to get a model fit for the first 5 strikes you displayed (formulaic though, for an unknown number of strikes in an unknown list for symbol,expiry,date combinations?)

BTW, Thank you very much for the assistance to this point.

Comment: You want to predict the volatility based on the strike, right?

Comment: Yes sir, that's the objective

Comment: I am trying to have all the coefs be represented on the same row as each strike as 5 different columns x4, x3, x2, x1, constant (4,3,2,1,0 as described in your answer).  With this approach reading any particular row in the df would provide all the information needed to calculate the fitted vol.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Joe, i followed your example and when i got to your equivalent of In[25] i got a long error message ending in KeyError: 'date'            My date is showing up as an "object" when i run df.dtypes, does that matter?

Comment: Oops! My bad. I forgot to reset the index on coeffs before the merge. It complained because it was trying to merge on 'date', 'expiry', 'symbol' but these formed the index of ```coeffs``` rather than columns. I've adjusted the answer. Since you're new to pandas you should probably break it down and print the result of each method and function call to see what's going on. The solution is a bit terse, in fairness